# Come si dice "no reason" in italiano?

Tags: translation

"No reason" è una espressione inglese che significa che non c'è nessuna ragione specifica per fare qualcosa. Per esempio:

> A: Why have you eaten the last cookie?
>   B: No reason.

Come direste "no reason" in italiano in una maniera idiomatica?:

> A: Perché hai mangiato l'ultimo biscotto?
>   B: ____.

Answer (score 8):

Io direi “Perché sì” o “Tanto per fare”.

Comment: Può essere anche “così”.

Comment: Io di solito dico *perché di sì*, non so se *perché sì* sia grammaticalmente più corretto o se lo siano entrambi, ma *perché sì* da solo mi suona più "militaresco".

Answer (score 1):

Anche "Senza motivo" direi, è più letterale come traduzione. Oppure: "così, senza motivo."